# Parallels - OS X Does giving the VM more RAM or more Video Memory/CPUs limit the mac?

Tags: virtual-machine, parallels

I installed parallels not too long ago and I am not sure what to set as the user settings..

My question is if I give the VM more ram does it limit my mac's ram when I run the VM? Same question with Video Memory and number of CPUs..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does not limit the number of CPUs available to the host - That setting is just telling Parallels how many CPUs it may use to run guest processes.

It will limit the amount of RAM available to the host. When Parallels starts up, it'll reserve the specified amount of memory, and then make it available to the guest.

I'm not 100% sure about video memory, but I expect that to work similar to RAM.